# FBAR: should I guess the approximate highest amount

Tags: united-states, fbar

I inherited a German investment account and the bank does not have the highest amount during the year because of market fluctuations. They have stated in a letter to me, that they can not provide me with the highest amount. I am worried about having to check the amount not known in the FBAR, but also don't want to give the wrong amount. I cashed in most of them shortly after inheriting, about a month later, so the amount it was, when I inherited the funds should be pretty close to the highest amount. What is the better option? How far off can you be and still be in compliance?

Comment: Why are you worried about checking "amount not known" if you actually don't know?

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica "amount not known" is for cases where you know there's an account but you don't have any access to it or its value not determined. That's not the situation here, the OP has access and can determine value.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the maximum amount known to you and save the communication with your bank for your records, should you need it for audit purposes.

> Determine the maximum value of each account (in the currency of that account) during the calendar year being reported. The maximum value of an account is a **reasonable approximation** of the greatest value of currency or nonmonetary assets in the account during the calendar year. Periodic account statements may be relied on to determine the maximum value of the account, provided that the statements fairly reflect the maximum account value during the calendar year.

https://www.fincen.gov/reporting-maximum-account-value

Answer (score 0):

You should not guess, but you should know. From what you described, you had the account for about a month. You'll need to check the currency fluctuations during that month, it shouldn't be that hard. Rounding up to the nearest hundred would probably be OK.

Comment: The bank has not provided me with ANY information, just the interest received for the whole year, which isn't even the whole time I had inherited the amount. They are keeping the account in my dead parents name and basically don't even show fluctuations. I can not look up any past amounts, the amounts I can see are very limited.

Comment: then what did you cash in?

Comment: @littleadv the way I read it, the bank can't provide a daily mark-to-market for the investments, in EUR. OP should report the max amount based on the available bank statements, then convert it to USD using the official exchange rate from the ECB, for example.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD I guess it's a question of facts and circumstances, it would likely be OK but we wouldn't know until FinCEN (or IRS, who's enforcing this) would start asking questions. However, more to the OP's question, it is still not "unknown". They're right to be concerned.